# Text alignment within a minipage

Tags: minipage

I want to create three rows of text. Each should start at the same distance from the left of the page. But that distance isn't just where the left margin ends; instead, the text should be centered in the middle of the page.

To try to achieve this, I tried the following:

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]
{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \Large
    Alpha\\
    \vspace{2mm}
    Beta\\
    \vspace{2mm}
    Gamma\\
\end{minipage}}
```

But this gave me the following output:

[image]

I have two questions:

1) Why are the three rows not aligned?

2) Changing the value of the `vspace` between `Alpha` and `Beta` actually only affects the gap between `Beta` and `Gamma`. Hence, the gaps between the three rows are not equal (to 2mm). Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \Large
    Alpha\\[2mm]
    Beta\\[2mm]
    Gamma
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]
{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \Large
    Alpha\par\vspace{2mm}
    Beta\par\vspace{2mm}
    Gamma
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

if this gives what you looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
Alpha\\
\vspace{2mm}
Beta\\
\vspace{2mm}
Gamma\\
```

then you create only one paragraph with the instructions:

```
Alpha\hfil\break\vadjust{\vskip2mm} Beta\hfil\break\vadjust{\vskip2mm} Gamma\hfil\break\par
```

Note the spaces before `Beta` and `Gamma`. These spaces occur here from the end lines where your `\vsapce{2mm}<space>` is written (spaces generated by token processor).

Now, this paragraph is broken to the lines:

```
Alpha\hfil
\vadjust{\vskip2mm} Beta\hfil
\vadjust{\vskip2mm} Gamma\hfil
```

The `\vadjust` primitive produced by `\vspace` LaTeX macro puts its vertical material below the current line, so the lines look like:

```
Alpha\hfil
<space>Beta\hfil
\vskip2mm
<space>Gamma\hfil
\vskip2mm
```

This is typical misunderstanding of LaTeX users with `\vspace` macro. What you need: understand more about TeX principles about vertical mode, horizontal mode, about tokenizer, about `\vadjust` primitive etc. But, unfortunately, these things are not documented in common LaTeX manuals.

**Edit** There is another problem (or common bug in LaTeX documents) in your code: the usage of `\\` at the end of paragraph, namely:

```
...Gamma\\
```

This is processed as

```
...Gamma\hfil\break<space>\par
```

and `\par` primitive runs `\unskip` (which removes the `<space>` from end of line) and adds `\nobreak\hskip\parfillskip\break`, so we have:

```
...Gamma\hfil\break\nobreak\hskip\parfillskip\break
```

`\nobreak` means `\penalty10000` and `\break` means `\penalty-10000` here. The `\hskip` and `\penalty` with value bigger than `-10000` are discardable (removable) items, only `\penalty-10000` (alias `\break`) is non-discardable. So, all items are removed after first `\break` except the last `\break` and we have:

```
...Gamma\hfil\break\break
```

When this material is divided into lines, the empty line is created after first `\break`. But this line does not have any stretchable material, so the warning: `Underfull hbox badnes 10000` occurs. Your example definitely makes a paragraph like this:

```
Alpha\hfil
<space>Beta\hfil
\vskip2mm
<space>Gamma\hfil
\vskip2mm
<empty line plus warning Underfull hbox>
```

And what you can do? Don't use `\\` inside paragraphs nor at the end of paragraph. If you need to achieve the same effect, simply close the current paragraph. Your example can be printed as three paragraphs. If you use `\vskip` primitive (instead `\vspace` LaTeX macro), then the behaviour is more intuitive, because `\vskip` closes the current paragraph when it is in horizontal mode. More precisely, `\vskip` adds `\par` token before itself in such situation. So the code:

```
Alpha
\vskip2mm
Beta
\vskip2mm
Gamma
```

does exactly, what you need. But your first word of the next paragraph must not be `Plus` or `Minus` (read more about `\vskip` in TeX documentation).